# how to check or declare array values of an array like an instanceof a Class/Entity

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, instanceof

In my symfony project I have an array `$productContainer` with some values like (php dump):

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "value1"
  1 => "value2"
]
```

I pass this array in the `Product` entity by `findBy` method in my controller like this:

```
$products = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')
                                ->findByValue($productContainer);
```

The results between the findBy method and the array values match very well.

But when I check if the **array** is **an instance** of my **class** `Product` like this:

```
dump($products instanceof Product);
die;
```

it retuns me : **false**

I understand that `$products` is an **array** and not an **object**, but how can I declare my array `$products` as an `instanceof` `Product` entity ?

### Edit

In order to be more precise, I need to declare or check if my values of array `$products` are `instanceof` `Product` because in the same controller, I have to pass array $products in a queryBuilder for another entity like this:

```
$entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity')
                              ->getEntityWithProducts($slug, $products);
```

I recover the array `$products` by a `$_POST` method (`Request $request`)
Its a controller method that I retun into JsonResponse, that why I proceed in that way.

Comment: Class instances are always objects.

Comment: This could not be reached, array would never be instance of class. Tell me, please, why do you need this?

Comment: If you query for product you get product or null, nothing else. Do not check for clear things. And also liek above, array never be object.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak, he would never receive clear instance of `Product` entity! It is because he uses `findBy` method - it never returns one object, it returns either array of objects (even if there is only one) or null. He need either to check each array member for `instanceof` or don't need to check any of them.

Comment: @IlyaYarkovets you're right, thank you!

Comment: No problem! And I suggest you to add a little modification into your answer: If he still wants to fetch an array of records through his query, the most simple and the only one right (imho!) variant is to check whether the result array is empty or not - if it is empty, nothing found, if not - there are some records and all(!) of them are instances of his `Product` entity. :)

Comment: @IlyaYarkovets You're absolutely right twice! I agree with you! But question little bit unclear...

Comment: @VladimirKovpak, it is not unclear, it's eh-h-hm... Let's agree that it is strange  to not offend anyone :)

Comment: @VladimirKovpak, offtop: btw, thanks for php test from your twitter ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `findOneByValue` instead `findByValue` if you need just one product.

Or
extract some one element from your received array,
because you receive array of entities after invoking `findByValue`.

Or
traverse all elements in received array to check them.

Or
maybe in your product repository present method `findByValue` that do some staff for you.

But anyway it sounds strange to check after doctrine that it returns for you appropriate class instance...

If you use something like `getArrayResult` you'll receive array, otherwise you'll receive instance of appropriate entity.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays can't be of some object class, but if I understand what you want to do, maybe you can try using array functions.

Try this

```
$test = array_reduce(
          $products, 
          function ($condition, $item) {
            return $condition && $item instanceof Product;
          }, 
          true
        );
// $test will be true if all elements of $products are instances 
// of 'Product', false otherwise
```